# In Rails, the input field is too long for Bootstrap modal window

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

When implementing Bootstrap 3 modal with Rails 4.2, the input field is way too long on Bootstrap modal form. The `width:100%` is not setting the width correctly as recommended by online posts. Here is modal form:

[image]

Here is the `rails` `new.html.erb`:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header clearfix">
    <div class="text-left">
    <h2><%=t('New ' + @for_which.sub('_', ' ').titleize) %></h2>
    </div>
  </div>

<%= form_for @misc_definition, html: {class: 'form-group'} do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label I18n.t(@for_which.sub('_', ' ').titleize), class:"control-label" %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control", style: 'width: 100%;' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label I18n.t('Ranking Index'), class:"control-label" %>
      <%= f.text_field :ranking_index, :placehoder => '1, 2, 3 ...', class: "form-control", style: 'width: 100%;' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label I18n.t("Brief Note") %>
      <%= f.text_field :brief_note,  :input_html => {:rows => 2}, class: "form-control", style: 'width: 100%;' %>
  </div>
  <%= f.hidden_field :for_which, :input_html => {:value => @for_which} %>

    <div class="tool-bar">
     <%= link_to t('Back'), misc_definitions_path(:for_which => @for_which, :subaction => @for_which), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
     <%= submit_tag t('Save'), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>  


<% end %>

</div>
```

This form is inserted in `new.js.erb':

```
$("#newmiscdef .modal-content").html('<%= j render(:file => "commonx/misc_definitions/new.html.erb") %>');
$("#newmiscdef").modal();
```

How to make the input fields fit in modal window?

Answer (score 3):

somewhere you have given width= 100% to input type, remove it, you need to specify label width and textbox width using bootstrap grid system please have a look at this

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Horizontal form</h2>
  <form class="form-horizontal" action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">          
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
      </div>
    </div>
    
   
  </form>
</div>
```

expand and run snippet to see effect

Comment: If the sum (grid of label + grid of input field) of the grid number is equal to 12, then the input fields goes beyond of modal window (same problem as width:100%). The sum of 6 works. Another way is set the width to 50% and it works for various sizes of screens.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I end up with width:50%. The code below works with various sizes of windows responsively.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header clearfix">
    <div class="text-left">
    <h2><%=t('New ' + @for_which.sub('_', ' ').titleize) %></h2>
    </div>
  </div>

<%= form_for @misc_definition, html: {class: 'form-group'} do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label I18n.t(@for_which.sub('_', ' ').titleize), class:"control-label" %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control", style: 'width: 50%;' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label I18n.t('Ranking Index'), class:"control-label" %>
      <%= f.text_field :ranking_index, :placehoder => '1, 2, 3 ...', class: "form-control", style: 'width: 50%;' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label I18n.t("Brief Note") %>
      <%= f.text_area :brief_note,  :rows => 2, class: "form-control", style: 'width: 50%;' %>
  </div>
  <%= f.hidden_field :for_which, :value => @for_which %>

    <div class="tool-bar">
     <%= link_to t('Back'), misc_definitions_path(:for_which => @for_which, :subaction => @for_which), :class => BUTTONS_CLS['action'] %>
     <%= submit_tag t('Save'), :class => BUTTONS_CLS['action'] %>
    </div>  


<% end %>

</div>
```